# How to pass a parameter out of an onClick

Tags: java, android

New to Android Studio. I'm creating an app project for practice and I am trying to create a Menu Activity. I want to test to see if I can mute sounds and hide the display of text (score) via a Menu UI. I get that I can use Intent to pass values back and forth between activities and that I can use those values to turn features on and off across the app.

I cannot figure out with a button and onClick how to get a variable to change so that I can pass it via Intent. I've only seen it done INSIDE the onClick. I'm trying to change the variable OUTSIDE the onClick.

Example Code:

```
    public class Menu extends AppCompatActivity {

    private boolean soundOn = true;
    private Button isSoundOn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

    isSoundOn = findViewById(R.id.isSoundOn_button);

    isSoundOn.setOnClickListener(v -> {
         soundOn = false;
    });
```

Now when I attempt to access the soundOn parameter and pass it on via Intent to another activity the value remains true, it never changes after the button is clicked.

I did figure out one trick, I can use intent and pass the value to the same activity, like so:

```
    soundOff.setOnClickListener(v -> {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Menu.this, Menu.class);
    intent.putExtra("soundOn", false);
    startActivity(intent);
```

This reloads the Activity after the button is clicked, it makes it appear as though a glitch happened as it is run, but I think that issue could be resolved via altering the transition animation...I think. However, this seems like a clumsy approach, especially in a Menu Activity that could have numerous settings to edit (sound, score, language, timer, color, background, etc.).

I get that I can have the onClick go back to the original Activity with the change, but I want to create a menu where I can have multiple selections made and then pass them all back to the original Activity.

I hope this makes sense, I know this is rather basic, but I'm new to this and my searching hasn't been able to yield a solution. Thanks.

Comment: android studio is just an IDE, helping you to code android, so unless you're asking about a feature of the IDE specifically, there's no need to use the tag or reference it in your question

Answer (score 0):

> Now when I attempt to access the soundOn parameter and pass it on via
> Intent to another activity the value remains true, it never changes
> after the button is clicked.

Lets start with keeping track of `soundOn`

1. When Menu activity is first launched    `soundOn = true`
2. When isSound button is clicked    `soundOn = false`

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Menu.this, Menu.class);
intent.putExtra("soundOn", soundOn); // false is the value that is extra.
startActivity(intent);
```

4. When MenuActivity is again launched due to the intent `soundOn = true` this is because of this line

```
private boolean soundOn = true; //<---
```

You are passing Extra in `intent` but you arent storing the `intents extra value` in `soundOn` 
Thats why it is true always

to solve this use need to Get the `Intent Extra` that you have passed and we do it in `onCreate` method

```
private boolean soundOn = true;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if(intent != null) { //  we need to get this cause when we first start our app we dont start it with any intents
        soundOn = intent.getExtra("soundOn");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing an intent to the same Activity you should retreive your intent on the `onCreate` method:

```
isSoundOn = intent.getBooleanExtra("soundOn", true) //true is the default parameter in case intent does not contain that key;
```

That way you are always checking your intent in case you need it.

You also need to use your variable in the intent; right now you are always setting it to false:

```
  soundOff.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Menu.this, Menu.class);
            intent.putExtra("soundOn", soundOn);
            startActivity(intent);
  }
```

There are other solutions, for example: you can use `SharedPreferences` for persisting your values and then call `this.recreate` to recreate Activity again and avoid using intents. Then you can retreive your `SharedPreferences`values on the `onCreate` method to do whatever you want.

Comment: `intent.getBooleanExtra("")` this can cause the app to crash when its first launch

Comment: @SwapnilPadaya No, it cant. Thats why you give a default param.

Comment: intent variable cant be found in onCreate(), and yeah you are right default is `True` if the key is not found. But in your solution `intent` itself is not found.

Comment: Well what I am saying is about `intent` variable itself its not even Define so it will crash.

Comment: Thank you Nacho - The SharedPreferences seems to be what I was searching for. I just watched a quick YouTube video and integrated it into my practice app and it seems to work. THANK YOU again!

Comment: @JasonW Nice to hear that. You should accept the answer for marking this as solved.